# Wierd jquery bug, when trying to append() after using wrap()

Tags: jquery, select, append

Using jQuery, I

1. Created a container
2. Wrapped an element with it
3. Selected the container by passing an object to its jQuery selector and tried to add an element to the container

Why doesn't element `append()`?

Look at this example here: [jsfiddle.net/Tngh4](http://jsfiddle.net/Tngh4/)

```
    var container = document.createElement("div");
    //Wrapping some random element with the container
    $("#randomElem").wrap(container);

    var elem = document.createElement("div");
    //Selecting element this way and using append results in a strange bug
    $(container).append(elem);
```

Comment: Please transfer the code you have from JSFiddle to here. We only consider as code, the code that exists in **the question *itself*** and ***not*** in external sources/websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.wrap wraps the element with a copy of the passed in element, not the passed in element itself.

> **A copy** of this structure will be wrapped around each of the elements in the set of matched elements. This method returns the original set of elements for chaining purposes.

http://api.jquery.com/wrap

Here's your fiddle to use an alternative to `.wrap` http://jsfiddle.net/Tngh4/1/

Comment: Thx. Now it looks so obvious. I can't believe that I missed it.